# PHP Any way to "Echo , Display, Print" a message in the middle of a loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I need to force my PHP page to display the message after each round in a loop .. not at the end of loop .. as i'm running an infinite loop.
the goal is that i have a script inside a page that runs a command on the server .. takes the output and compares the data with in IF statement if it checks it displays a message .. if not .. it sleeps for three seconds and runs the loop again.
the problem is when i run the php file from a command line on the server it does exactly what it should do .. displays a message every 3 seconds (not pressing the confirmation button).. but when i run it in a browser it displays nothing (it waits for the loop to end!)
not sure if my below example will serve the purpose though.

```
<?php
while (1==1) {
  $answer = shell_exec ("COMMAND'");
  list($src, $app, $cid, $non, $flag, $dur, $exten) = explode("!", $answer);

  if ($cid > 0) {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
      var r=confirm('You have a call from $cid: Show Data?') 
      if (r==true)
      {
        OPEN A WEB PAGE INSIDE AN IFRAME
      }
    </script>";

    //header( 'refresh: 15; url=monit.php' );
    flush();
    sleep(10);
  }
  else {
    //header( 'refresh: 1; url=monit.php' );
    sleep(1);
  }
}
?>
```

Please note that i tried to use "header()" function to reload the page however i don't want to reload the page itself (will create a complication inside the parent page)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please indent your code. I can barely read it. As for your question, no. You must do that with AJAX, as PHP can't print text like this (the browser will usually timeout).

Comment: Turn `zlib`/`gzip` off if you haven't already.

Comment: did you use ob_start() at any point?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to check mentioned in the [manual page](http://uk.php.net/flush) for the flush function:

> flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser

---

> Several servers, especially on Win32, will still buffer the output from your script until it terminates before transmitting the results to the browser.

---

> Server modules for Apache like mod_gzip may do buffering of their own that will cause flush() to not result in data being sent immediately to the client.

There are also some config file options that need to be checked mentioned in the comments

> If flush() function does not work. You must set next options in php.ini like:

`output_buffering = Off

 ;output_handler =

 zlib.output_compression = Off

 ;zlib.output_handler =`

I've also notice there are commented out lines to cause the page to refresh - you do not need to refresh the page to see the new output, the browser should show the page as still loading until the script has completed.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said unless you have full control over the server this would be impossible to implement, and even if you did if you wanted to keep the connection open for a considerable length of time it would probably time out, requiring client-side continuation.

Thus, it would probably be a better idea to use AJAX, for example:

ping.php

```
$answer = shell_exec('COMMAND');
$r = array();
list($r['src'], $r['app'], $r['cid'], $r['non'], $r['flag'], $r['dur'], $r['exten']) = explode("!", $answer);
if($r['cid'] > 0)
  $r['success'] = true;
else
  $r['success'] = false;
echo json_encode($r);
```

Script in your public HTML/PHP file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // If you're using jQuery...
  var ping = function() {
    $.ajax('ping.php', {
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.success && confirm('You have a call from ' + data.cid + ': show data>'))
          $('iframe').attr('src', 'new_page.php');
      }
    });
  };
  setInterval(ping, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop this into your htaccess (turns of gzip):

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

and to echo the message and flush output buffer do this in your loop:

```
echo $msg;
ob_flush();
flush();
```